# is there any simple way to format the date in php?

Tags: php, date, format

is there any function to format this kind of `'5/1/2011'` date to `'2011,1,5'` to this in PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via a [regular expression](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pcre.php):

```
$new_str = preg_replace('#(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)#', '$3,$2,$1', $str);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use PHP [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function

In your case this should do the trick:

```
$date = '5/1/2011';
echo date('Y,j,n', strtotime($date));
```

Comment: This is the best answer because you should really be formatting date objects and not just replacing string.

Comment: But only works if strtotime can figure out what the date should be. Try it on '1/2/3' and see if that works out ok for you. strtotime is useful, but it's not *THE* best solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?
function transdate($date) {
     $dates = explode("/", $date);
     return $dates[2].",".dates[1].",".dates[0];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = implode(',', array_reverse(explode('/', '5/1/2011')));
```

Answer (score 0):

A newer and better way to do this as of PHP 5.2 is the [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php):

```
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('n/j/Y', '5/1/2011');
echo $datetime->format('Y,j,n');
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/r7IBqx)